# formar una variable a traves de una cadena de texto

Tags: vba

tengo el siguiente codigo, lo que quiero hacer es recuperar los valores a1 hasta la a6 por medio del bucle for..

```
introducir el código aquí
Sub prueba()
  Dim i, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6 As Integer
  
  ' valores de las variables
      a1 = 2
      a2 = 4
      a3 = 100
      a4 = 50
      a5 = 25
      a6 = 30
  
  'bucle principal
   For i = 1 To 6
       MsgBox ("valor de a" & i & ": " & "A" & i)
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Para lo que quieres hacer necesitas aprender a manejar matrices (llamados también arrays o arreglos). https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no está muy bien desarrollada, pero bueno:

```
Option Base 1

Sub prueba()

    Dim i, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6 As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant
    ' valores de las variables
    a1 = 2
    a2 = 4
    a3 = 100
    a4 = 50
    a5 = 25
    a6 = 30
    
    ReDim arr(6)
    arr(1) = a1
    arr(2) = a2
    arr(3) = a3
    arr(4) = a4
    arr(5) = a5
    arr(6) = a6
    
    'bucle principal
     For i = 1 To 6
         MsgBox "valor de a" & i & ": " & arr(i)
     Next

End Sub
```